# Is it possible to conditionally format the third decimal of a number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a series of formulas that are returning values with three decimal places. Since these are dollar amounts, and I do want to see the last decimal, I was hoping there would be a way to format the third decimal so that the rest of the value looks more like a dollar figure. For instance, instead of seeing this:

**1.675**

I'd like to see this

**1.67**5

Or even better, show that final digit, the "5" in this case, as unbolded medium yellow so that "1.67" becomes the focus and the "5" becomes a little additional information.

I've been studying the number formatting and the conditional formatting, and thus far I don't think it's possible. But I'm hoping someone can prove my assertion wrong and show me the way.

Comment: Do it the simple way; format the cell to only show 2 decimals. If this is a dollar amount, it would be pretty weird to show an unbolded, coloured amount as the trailing digit.

Comment: Well that tenth of a cent has it's value to me in this context. Let's me see the tendency of the average cost per click (online campaign ads) toward higher or lower costs. The costs per click are generally under 15 cents. They add up, however, so knowing the tendency of that last tenth of a percent helps me decide if I want to cancel this campaign or increase visibility to that campaign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention researching number formatting, which is probably the most seamless option.  You can try a custom number format like this "0.00(0)" or this "0.00  0" which will show values as "1.23(4)" and "1.23 4".  I don't think you can set character specific colors though using this method.

As Teylyn points out, you can do this with VBA, but you have to set your cell NumberFormat to text which is annoying. What I would do is make the macro toggle itself and add it to the quick access toolbar so you can easily toggle it on and off.  Here is an example that toggles the format for cell A1.

```
Sub ToggleSpecialFormat()
If Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@" Then
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("A1").Formula = Range("A1").Formula
Else
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1").Formula = Range("A1").Formula
    Range("A1").Characters(5, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This wins. I'm happy enough with the first paragraph above. It's not color coding, but you've brought me to realize I have more options available than I realized. Thank you very much for taking the time to provide this information, Dan.

Comment: So I've opted on this for now, which is working well enough:

#,###.#0 (0\/"10");-#,###.#0 (0\/"10");0

A little clumsy, but sufficient.

Numbers come out looking like:

**.66 (8/10)**

Answer (score 0):

There is no number format or VBA trick in Excel that I'm aware of that will allow a different font/color/weight of an individual digit in a decimal number.

You can create a VBA routine that can create a text string and format parts of that text with specific font or color attributes, but the result will be text and not a number that is suitable for consumption in formulas.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: This is what I was guessing, Teylyn. I'll leave this open for a while just in case someone out there has by chance stumbled upon a means or has an idea for another way to approach this altogether. I appreciate your taking the time.